# Material design 3 web components in my react project

Tags: css, reactjs, web, frontend

I'm currently working on a React project and have successfully integrated the Material Design 3 web components library. However, I've encountered an issue when it comes to customizing the provided components using CSS styling values. I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively customize these components to match the project's design requirements.

If any of you have experience with using Material Design 3 web components in a React project and know how to customize them with CSS styling values, your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please elaborate your question with the current progress, so the reader will find it easier to grasp. You may add some code snippets from your current project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.